# How to hide image when hovering on a link in a different div

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have looked all over for this and I can't seem to figure it out. I have a list of links that show an image when hovering over each one. I also have a default image in that same place holder when no links are being hovered over. How do I make that default image disappear when the links showing their images. I don't want to use backgrounds to cover the default image.

https://jsfiddle.net/76tnfh96/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="links">
<p class="default_img"><a><img src="http://thedeskdoctors.com/Images/LifePreserver.jpg"></a></p>
        <ul id="over" class="links">
                <li><a>Link 1<span><img src="http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IPOLogo.png"></span></a></li>
                <li><a>Link 2<span><img src="http://mojosimon.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/large-company.jpg?w=600"></span></a></li>
                <li><a>Link 3<span><img src="http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/seo-for-small-business-300x200.jpg"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

.links .default_img a {
  top:100px;
    float:right;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
    background:#000000;
    position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
/*Link position*/
ul.links {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:100px;
}
.links li {
    width:200px;
    color:#000000;
}

/*Hover Image Position/transition out*/
.links li a span, .links li a b {
    position:absolute;
    right:8px;
    top:-999em;
    display: none;
}

.links li a:hover span {
    top:24px;
    display: block;
}

</style>
```

Comment: This is impossible with CSS only, you cannot select up the DOM, if you want to i can show you a JS solution.

Comment: If I can't do it in CSS only then JS is fine. How do I do it is JS? Thanks.

Comment: Please refer tho [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35581539/3880255), it works in all browsers, you just have to edit the `hidden` class as you wish.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can leave your whole Markup like what you already had, and add this JavaScript code to your page. You do not need to add any frameworks, and this runs on all browsers.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#over a");

[].forEach.call(links, function(value) {

  var default_image = document.querySelector(".links .default_img a");

  value.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
   default_image.classList.add("hidden");
  });

  value.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
   default_image.className = default_image.className.replace(/\hidden\b/,'');
  });
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/1rw5vyoh/)

(The example might lag a bit because your CSS moves your images like wild)

[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/1rw5vyoh/1)

(Moved the images for better testing purposes)

Comment: There was no talk of a javascript solution needed. Css was implied.

Comment: There is no flexible CSS solution whatsoever, as it is impossible to crawl up the DOM, anything else is hackish.

Comment: My solution does not go up the dom thats why i pasted the html code to show this - please view and digest before voting.

Comment: That is what i mean, you completely change possible dependencies. Imagine working for a client that wants this functionality, now you change the markup and possibly break some code. **That is hackish!**

Answer (score 0):

With jquery:

```
$("li a").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".default_img").eq(0).hide();
});

$("li a").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".default_img").eq(0).show();
});
```

Comment: Don't make people go for a full-blown framework for five lines of code, a complete waste of resources!

Comment: using pure javascript instead of a full-blown framework is a complete waste of time in most cases

Comment: Oh well, i'm quitting SO it's getting worse every day.

Answer (score -1):

Just changed a couple of things so you don't have to use jQuery/javascript. To be able to hover action another non dependent element you would need javascript as that would be called a disjointed rollover.

```
        <ul id="over" class="links">
                <li><a>Link 1<span><img src="http://thedeskdoctors.com/Images/LifePreserver.jpg"></span></a></li>    
                <li><a>Link 2<span><img src="http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/IPOLogo.png"></span></a></li>
                <li><a>Link 3<span><img src="http://mojosimon.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/large-company.jpg?w=600"></span></a></li>
                <li><a>Link 4<span><img src="http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/seo-for-small-business-300x200.jpg"></span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div> 



 <style type="text/css">

/*Link position*/
ul.links {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    width:100px;
}
.links li {
    width:200px;
    color:#000000;
}

/*Hover Image Position/transition out*/

.links li a span {
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    display: none;
}
.links li a span img {
    width: 100px; height:100px;
}
.links li a:hover span {
    top:24px;
    display: block;
  background: none;
}
.links li:first-of-type a span, .links li:first-of-type a:hover span{
  display:block;
  background: url(http://thedeskdoctors.com/Images/LifePreserver.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
</style>
```

Changed image sizes just so it would fit in view while testing.

Comment: Does not work properly, also never use absolute paths in CSS!

Comment: Nothing wrong with absolute paths while demonstrating another point that was asked for! @Clemens Himmer.

Comment: Everything is wrong with absolute paths, remove the URL in the CSS and your example is worth even less. Also it **does not work**.